# Is it possible to use BigqueryOperator to store data result into several partition in one call?

Tags: airflow

Currently I have this query_to_table_x.sql

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c
FROM table_x
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = {{ execution_date }}
```

I have airflow_dag.py as below

```
def func(dag):
  day_no_dash = {{ ds_nodash }}
  day = {{ ds }}
  transform_op = BigQueryOperator(
            sql='query_to_table_x.sql',
            params={
                'execution_date': day
            },
            destination_dataset_table='project.dataset.result_table_x' + '$' + day_no_dash,
                time_macros
            ),
            task_id='job_to_get_result_table_x',
            create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'
  return operators

dag = DAG(
    'daily_job',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="00 02 * * *",
)
result_table_x = func(dag)
```

In the case above, I will run query_to_table_x.sql and store it into project.dataset.result_table_x$yyyyMMdd.
Example: today is 2020-04-06, so I will run run query_to_table_x.sql with filter `_PARTITIONTIME = '2020-04-06'` then store the result into `project.dataset.result_table_x$20200406`

I have plan to run this DAG not in daily basis, but in biweekly.
Question, is it possible to have one call of BigQueryOperator but select several dates, then store the result into different PARTITIONTIME.
So that I will have query like this

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c
FROM table_x
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB({{ execution_date }}, INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND {{ execution_date }}
```

But I don't know if it is available for BigqueryOperator to have that kind of parameter to be set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using column partitioned tables instead? Then the data will land automatically in the right partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create operators dynamically within your airflow_dag.py using loops.

If you translate the following SQL logic to python `TIMESTAMP_SUB({{ execution_date }}, INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND {{ execution_date }}` you can create an iterator which will be used to build the DAG flow.

So your DAG would look something like:

```
for date in ['2020-04-06', '2020-04-07', '...']:
    transform_op = BigQueryOperator(...)
```

This will create N BigQueryOperator tasks, where each one will query & overwrite a single date. (Make sure the 'task_id' is unique for each BigQueryOperator instance)

Note these N operators will query BigQuery multiple times (14 times in your case), but, as you work with ingestion time partitioning, costs should remain the same as you only scan a single day with each task.

Comment: This will be costly if I have multiple date selected in 1 job ya? Example I have query ```SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = {{ execution_date }}) AS table_a_filtered LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB({{ execution_date }}, INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND {{ execution_date }} ) AS table_b_filtered ON table_a_filtered.key = table_b_filtered.key```

Comment: "Bytes Processed" wise when the partition is _PARTITIONTIME, the following procedures will "cost" the same

1. Single large query:
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE _PARTITIONTIME TIMESTAMP_SUB({{ execution_date }}, INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND {{ execution_date }

2. 90 x smaller queries
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = '2020-04-..'

Note when running 90 x smaller, you have to make sure you stay within BQ's concurrency quota etc..